# give value to items of spinner and use them in calculation

Tags: java, android

I'm designing an app that has 4 spinners a text view and a button and according to what they choose it calculates price of translation service.

I want to know how to assign value to an item in spinner and then use it in calculation.

For example one of the items is English so I want to give value 2 so when that person clicks on English value 2 be used in a formula like below.

Result = Value of item selected in spinner 1 * Value of item selected in spinner 2 *Value of item selected in spinner 3 *Value of item selected in spinner 4

Any hint would be useful

Comment: Why don't u go with if-else, if (spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("english")) {value1=2} and like wise for all spinners

Comment: Tnx for your answer so I use it in onSelectedItemClickedListener Method?

Comment: value 1 is not recognized by android studio

Comment: I don't say value 1 , what i said is value1 which is a variable name (you can use any variable name)

Comment: I got it , thanks . but it doesn't allow int

Comment: You have to type them without space. Its just a variable. You can write value1 but not value 1 (note it has space)

Comment: This is the error:
Required : java.lang.string
Found:int

Comment: Still you don't get it bro. You cannot use space in variable name. int value1 = 2; It will work. but int value 1 = 2; this will throw you error

Comment: believe me there is no space

Answer (score 0):

The best way is as below:

**1. Make a custom Class**

```
class MyClass {
    public int Id;
    public String Title;
    public long Price;
    public MyClass (int id,String title,long price){
      Id = id;
      Title = title;
      Price = price;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
    return Title;
    }
}
```

**2. Use Array Adapter for the spinner with custom model:**

```
new ArrayAdapter<MyClass>(getApplicationContext(),
        android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, YOUR_LIST_OF_ITEMS);
```

**3. Whenever you want to get the selected item, just do this:**

```
((MyClass)YOUR_SPINNER.getSelectedItem()).Id
```

by this way you can have access to any parameter in your model.

> **Important Note** :
>   Do not forget to override toString method in your custom class. that is the method to show title in the spinner.

By using this approach, you would not need to set any listener listener or hold a reference to selected item.

> **EDIT** : use string instead of any custom class

If you want to use string array that is ok. At the end when you are getting the selected item, just search in the array and find the index and use that.

```
String selectedItem = YOUR_SPINNER.getSelectedItem().toString();
int index = YOUR_STRING_ARRAY_LIST.indexOf(selectedItem);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer Mr.Heshmatinia. I have a question those Id Title and price refers to what?

Comment: my list was Farsi that's why I didnt post them here

Comment: They refer to anything you like! That is just a show case to help you to understand you can use any Custom model. If you do not need them, just remove them. @LoveProgramming

Comment: <string-array name="time">
        <item name="usual">عادی</item>
        <item name="semiusual">نیمه فوری</item>
        <item name="quick">فوری</item>
    </string-array>

Comment: so here how I use them in my class

Comment: i Edit my answer @LoveProgramming

Comment: Thanks .so I try to see if my problem is solved I accept it as correct answer

Comment: Is there any way I contact you?